# Can a 12v base signal be used to switch a v5 device through a transistor?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors

I see lots of examples of using low voltage (like from a microprocessor) to switch 12v. I want to do the opposite. Is that okay to do, or should I use a relay? What other components will I need?

The project is supply power to an AtTiny85 when a 10-16v (headlight on a motorcycle) turns on. I will be using a LM2937 (or you can recommend another) to provide power the 3.3v source.

Comment: So you can just attach the regulator input to the headlamp high side, right?

Comment: Indeed there are simpler ways than a transistor switch for this.  But to address your question, yes, just choose a larger base resistor to keep the base current reasonable.

Comment: Connect a usb car charger to the switched headlight power. When the headlight is on, so will the usb output and your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a buck switching regulator (output 3v3) connected to your headlight wiring. No need for a switch. Don't use a linear regulator for this because it might dissipate too much power and burn (load dependant).

Buck regulators are near enough 90% efficient at transferring power so it will burn very little power. One word of warning is that with any regulator you should rate its input to withstand at least 42V. 42V is a recommended limit for surges in normal automotive environments although a 60V capable regulator will be better and, there are a few. Maybe [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54061.pdf) TI one: -

[image]

Comment: An ATtiny85 by itself won't draw much current and so should not produce much heat for a linear regulator rated for the input voltage.  However, if there are additional components running at the regulated voltage, then a switcher could be justified.

Comment: @ChrisStratton there tends to be many offerings of cheap switchers that can handle the higher voltages too. Probably because there just isn't many reasons to use a 500mA linear reg powered at 40V (e.g.) because of the heatsink requirements